# How to properly create a Docker image for Angular apps?

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to build a Docker image for my Angular app, this specific version is supposed to run for dev env, so code wasn't prod build. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["ng", "serve", "-o"]
```

The image builds, but when I try to run the container from it

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 a42ac6b0a4c0
```

I get this message

```
Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli".
This likely means your local installation is broken. Please reinstall your packages.
```

Comment: Tried it on my machine with a sample project. Worked fine for me.

Comment: seems like your local CLI version is different, remove node modules on host machine and then build the docker image. as `COPY . .` this steps overide your existing node modules that is installed in `npm install` in docker

Comment: I've run a couple of tests on my machine and it works for me. So I assume that the problem relies on what you copy. If the node_modules exists, it'll override the content of your node-modules in the docker container. Try adding `node_modules` in the .dockerignore.

Comment: For Complete Docker beginners, here is how you can quickly run Angular inside Docker https://thecodeframework.com/run-angular-app-inside-a-docker-container-in-5-mins/

Answer (score -2):

Removing the latest tag wont help. I suspect its not able to resolve version of @angular/cli as your local and global version are different. Can you share your package.json ? 
You might need to install the global version same as local one. 
Hope this helps.
[Edited the Answer]